# Is it possible to create `TestEnvironment` of `@firebase/rules-unit-testing` in Jest context and use it in React Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, detox

I'm building end-to-end testing with Detox for my React Native App.
I use Firebase as infrastructure, so I tried to run end-to-end testing using Firebase Emulator.

To run end-to-end testing, I need to fill data in the database, which is Firestore on Firebase Emulator, to create a specific context for a test.

However, the problem is that it is not possible to use `TestEnvironment` of `@firebase/rules-unit-testing` created in Jest context from the React Native App. `TestEnvironment` seems like works as a sandbox so that the changes are not generally shared through the Firebase emulator.

I searched for ways to pass `TestEnvironment` object to the Detox device, but couldn't find it.
The only way seems to be to use `firebase-admin`, but I wonder if this is the best option. It would be nice if there is any way to use `TestEnvironment` because it provides some useful functions for testing, such as `withSecurityRulesDisabled` and `clearFirestore`.

I wonder how others are implementing end-to-end tests for Firebase + React Native.